# How to display message based on user input from scanned file

Tags: java, class, java.util.scanner, java-io, println

I have a class that creates a text file based on user input for price and puts a time stamp and I can then read the file in another class.

I'm trying to figure **how to print a message if the price is different then the day before by 10% or more.** Basically **how can I take the information from the text file and figure out if the price changed by 10% between the 2 days for the same time, so 12 pm on the first day and 12 pm on the next day.**

For example if at 11 am on Tuesday the value is 50, and the value is 60 on Wednesday, it should print "price at 11 is more than 10%"

This is the code for creating the file:

```
class Main{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Price: ");
        float price = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Price:" + " " + price);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now(); 
        DateTimeFormatter formatDT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDT = dateTime.format(formatDT);
        scan.close();

        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("price.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
        {
            out.println(price + " " + formattedDT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

The price.txt looks like this:

```
50 29-09-2020 11:49:54
55 29-09-2020 12:54:41
60 29-09-2020 13:08:16
58 29-09-2020 14:08:21
...
60 30-09-2020 11:29:34
56 30-09-2020 12:34:21
60.3 30-09-2020 13:48:36
58.1 30-09-2020 14:18:11
```

and here is how I read the price.txt file:

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File readFile = new File("price.txt");
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(readFile);
            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String fileContent = fileReader.nextLine();
                System.out.println(fileContent);

            }
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file was not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please describe your problem.

Comment: Sorry I will try to make it clearer

Comment: Is the timestamp 12:54:41 truncated to 12 or rounded to closest hour 13? If it is rounded to 13 which value will be used: 55 12:54:41 or 60 13:08:16?

Comment: Hi @haba713 it's truncated to 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

- `Files.lines(...)` for reading the file line by line
- `Stream<String>` for iterating through the lines
- `String.split(...)` to split each line to price and time parts
- `LocalDateTime.parse(...)` to convert time part to `LocalDateTime`.
- 2 x 24 matrix `Double[][]` for buffering hourly prices for two days
- Modulo operator `%` for switching between even and odd days.

See this implementation:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFile {
    
    private static final DateTimeFormatter format =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double[][] prices = new Double[2][24];
        AtomicInteger prevLineDayIdx = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("price.txt"))) {
                stream.forEach(line -> {
                String[] ary = line.split(" ", 2);
                Double price = Double.parseDouble(ary[0]);
                LocalDateTime timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(ary[1], format);
                int dayIdx = (int) timestamp.toLocalDate().toEpochDay();
                int timeIdx = timestamp.getHour();
                if (dayIdx != prevLineDayIdx.get()) {  // Clear price buffer for 
                    if (prevLineDayIdx.get() != -1) {  // supporting line step > 1 days
                        for(int idx = prevLineDayIdx.get(); idx < dayIdx - 1; idx ++) {
                            prices[idx%2] = new Double[24];
                        }
                    }
                    prevLineDayIdx.set(dayIdx);
                }
                Double previousPrice = prices[(dayIdx - 1)%2][timeIdx];
                if (previousPrice != null &&
                        Math.abs(previousPrice - price)/previousPrice >= 0.1d) {
                    System.out.println("The price " + price + " on " + 
                            format.format(timestamp) + 
                            " differs 10% or more from the price " + 
                            previousPrice + 
                            " at the same time yesterday."); 
                }
                prices[dayIdx%2][timeIdx] = price;
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked great! I have a minor error, I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Can you [share](https://pastebin.com) your price.txt?

Comment: Sure, https://pastebin.com/CfLc87J4, I removed the seconds in the time as I decided it wasn't needed in my project.

Comment: I changed the format string accordingly `H:mm:ss` → `HH:mm`. However, I can't reproduce `NullFormatException`. See the output [here](https://pastebin.com/HkeZKBuB).

Comment: Thanks so much! I just figured out the problem, I had some extra empty lines after the 48 lines of the price.txt file. Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it!